# Why does phone keep switching off?

Tags: htc-desire-z

I have an HTC Desire Z which I have bought 3 months ago and I usually use it for phone calls. I don't have many apps in it. Sometimes when I call from my phone it switches off and then I have to remove and reinsert the battery to restart it.
What could be going wrong here? I have Android version 2.2 on my phone.

Comment: Sounds like a kernel panic.

Comment: Wats the solution?

Comment: Hacker solution: Root it and flash a new kernel. Mainstream consumer solution: Restore to factory settings and see if that helps, or go to your wireless carrier store and have them flash your phone.

Comment: @kchau Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hacker solution: [Root](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Desire_Z%3a_Rooting) it and [flash](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/koush/32771-faq-what-rom-manager-how-do-i-use.html) a new [kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=796385).

Mainstream consumer solution: Restore to factory settings and see if that helps, or go to your wireless carrier store and have them flash your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Battery Monitor Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=ccc71.bmw), and the companion app [Process Monitor Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=ccc71.pmw).

These will display and log the battery temperature and CPU usage respectively.
Process Monitor will also let you see a list of the most active processes.

This may help you learn what's happening on the phone before you go as far as restoring factory settings or flashing.